# setStatusBarColor not working [Lollipop]

Tags: android

How can I change status bar color? I am building with 5.0 and my target sdk is 21 and this code is not working...

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
    try {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.RED);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the OS of your device ?

Comment: @OrestSavchak lollipop

Comment: Just curious, why you doing try and catch here? Maybe you can share the code in your build.gradle file and stlyes.xml file.

Answer (score 11):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)) says about setStatusBarColor method, that

> "For this to take effect, the window must be drawing the system bar
>   backgrounds with FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS and
>   FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS must not be set. "

So for me, this worked (note the "addFlags" line in the code):

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

Comment: But this keeps the status bar elevation level too.